# command fails on jenkins, but works on terminal

Tags: jenkins, fastlane, fastlane-snapshot

I'm working on using fastlane screengrab/snapshot to take screenshots of my android and ios app. When I run them locally on terminal, they work perfectly, but when I run them from jenkins, they fail. I'm using macOS. 
**Android:**

```
/Users/shared/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -avd Pixel_API_22 &
fastlane screengrab
```

(These 2 are in a .sh)

> The first line failed: PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please
>   define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT

**iOS:**

```
fastlane snapshot
```

it failed while trying to build a test because of an provisioning profile error:

```
xcodebuild -showBuildSettings -scheme UITests -project ./abc.xcodeproj
```

(this is a command that fastlane snapshot execute automatically)

Again, they both run smoothly on terminal (I ran them in the same workspace as junkins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-check the environment settings after executing your job in Jenkins: you might see differences with the same environment settings as seen with your user account in command-line (where it is working)

The username might be different (if your Jenkins server/agent runs with another account).

The [OP Son Nguyen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8355412/son-nguyen) confirms the PATH issue:

> the developer who set up jenkins put a wrong path to android sdk, so I was able to run the android part by fixing the path.

And the OP adds:

> `fastlane` was installed in `/usr/local/bin` while jenkins was in `/User/myUser`: So, somehow they didn't work well together.
>   I reinstalled `fastlane` in `/User/myUser` and it worked.

Comment: I use the same user for both jenkins and terminal. I tried to export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT with the sdk path, still doesn't work

Comment: Then the is another difference, in the PATH probably

Comment: I checked jenkins config and the developer who set up jenkins put a wrong path to android sdk, so I was able to run the android part by fixing the path. Any suggestion for ios why it fails to build the test from jenkins?

Comment: @SonNguyen No suggestion except there must be again a difference, either in term of environment/path or in term of file content.

Comment: I finally figured it out. fastlane was installed in /usr/local/bin while jenkins was in /User/myUser so somehow they didn't work well together. I reinstalled fastlane in /User/myUser and it worked

Comment: @SonNguyen Great! I have included your comments in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

This got it working for me.

I had to include this at the top of my script :

```
     #!/bin/zsh
     source ~/.zshrc
```

and my .zshrc had this:

```
    export PATH="$PATH:"/usr/local/bin/
    export SSL_CERT_FILE=/etc/ssl/cert.pem # for openssl error
    export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/jenkins/Library/Android/sdk
```